# color the log output (stdout) in perl

Tags: regex, linux, string, perl, unix

I'm sorry for typos
i have a log file like this:

```
mynum[85295365] | yournum[3201410] | mymessage[4 ????? 4 off] | MSGLen[1]
```

i would coloring output like this

```
mynum == foreground blue  
yournum == foreground yellow  
and mymessage == foreground green.
```

i have a problem for coloring mymessage.
I tried the following code:

```
if($currentLine=~m/mymessage\[([\w+\d+\S]+){1,}\]/){  
$mymessage=$1;  
$outM="$mymessage";  
$currentLine=~s/mymessage\[([\w+\d+\S]+){1,}\]/mymessage[$cg$outM$crs]/g;}
```

and no result did not.
help me :(((((

Comment: Are you working on Linux, or Windows, or ... ?

Comment: i am working on solaris

Answer (score 1):

use the [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) CPAN module. It allows you to color screen output using ANSI escape sequences

Comment: i can`t detect `4 ????? 4 off` and i can print colorized mymessage. how i do detect content in mymessage?

Comment: if content mymessage Conjoined `4?????4off`, print colorized. but if separate not coloring in out put.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
mymessage\[(.+?)\]
```

Then your code becomes:

```
if ($currentLine =~ /mymessage\[(.+?)\]/) {
    $mymessage = $1;  
    $outM = $mymessage;  
    $currentLine =~ s/mymessage\[(.+?)\]/mymessage[$cg$outM$crs]/g;
}
```

Comment: when mymessage string have a whitespace, for example "????? 2" or "hsf ? 32 ????".

Comment: @lehr88: Sorry, I don't get you. he regex works fine in any case as `.+?` matches one or more any character.